# Computing Standard Errors from Kenward-Rogers with Parallel Processing

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate Standard Errors using Kenward-Rogers in R. Unfortunately, my RAM is insufficient for this heavy task. I was wondering if I could parallelize the process. I tried different approaches so far, but nothing worked.

```
library(parameters)
library(lmerTest)
library(lmtest)

rc_fit <- lmer(trstep ~ lrscale + (lrscale|cntry),
                data = df,
                REML = TRUE)

kenward_fit <- se_kenward(rc_fit)
```

This `se_kenward` is the function I would like to parallelize. Thank you very much in advance!

I tried different approaches from the `doParallel` package, but nothing worked.

Comment: Parallelization doesn't help to save memory.

Comment: Is there another way to keep the code running? Because it aborts as soon as the memory is full.